# An exception occured while trying to convert String "EN" to type "Java.lang.long"

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP, I have the following exception while populating drop down value.

```
........
<option value="Mr">MR</option>
<option value="Doctor[ServletException "/web-inf/pages/account.jsp"] An exception occured while trying to convert String "EN" to type "Java.lang.long"
.......
```

The value that i have passed is "Doctor of Philoshopy"

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: We'll need to see the actual code of the JSP to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help without some more information. Actual code or more details.

Comment: the exception message is telling you that **an exception** has occurred. *You* need to investigate which one it is by reading the server logs. If you don't understand the exception in the logs, post it here with the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make `Long` `Object` from `"EN"` `String` it is exceptional thing so it has been thrown. :)

Post code so that I can explain you more

Comment: I have populated some collection into Drop down. The collection only have Mr, Doctor of philoshopy, MD. The Jsp page is not loaded properly. It has problem when assigning value "Doctor of Philoshopy".

Comment: Please see my code below: <select name="suffix" id="suffix"> <option value="">Please select</option> <c:foreach items="${listofSuffixes}" var="item"> <option value="<c:out value='${item.description}'/>"> <c:out value="${item.value}"/> </option> </c:foreach> </select>

Comment: @Srinivasan you are casting string to long, please post class code for list of suffixes

Comment: Yes. This is tried to convert a long number which is came from DB.